# this keyword in JavaScript: please why does the alert say hello 521

Tags: javascript, object, variables, this, alert

Please why does the alert display hello 521

```js
"use strict";

let user = {
  name: "John",
  greet: `hello ${this.name}`
};

alert(user.greet);
```

Comment: this.name is not the user's name but the window's name because `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: I know there is a global this in browsers called window, but it's in an object and I thought this takes in the object it is in

Comment: 'this' refers to the caller. For your code to work, give user.name instead of this.name

Comment: Tried that but it gives an error that says cannot access user before initialization

Comment: It works on the browser but not in node.js